# Projections of a 3D Surface in R

Tags: python, r, 3d, plotly, surface

I have created a 3D plot and now I would like to create a heat map of projections of this 3D surface in 2D using R. Here is a reproducible code of the 3D plot that I tried

```
library(plotly)
kd <- with(MASS::geyser, MASS::kde2d(duration, waiting, n = 50))
p <- plot_ly(x = kd$x, y = kd$y, z = kd$z) %>% add_surface()
```

I have found a python version of doing this using the same library.
https://plot.ly/python/2d-projection-of-3d-surface/

Comment: `image(kd$x,kd$y,kd$z)` is enough or you want both the heatmap and the surface in the same figure ?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Thanks for getting back. I am looking to have both the heatmap and surface in the same figure. I tried searching a lot but couldn't find someone doing something like this in R - found lot in matlab and in python

Comment: I've found [this](https://plot.ly/~empet/13818/bivariate-gaussian-mixture-and-its-contour-plot/#code) but it seems a bit complex.

Comment: @s_t Good find. I was looking at it. And seems to be really complex. Found it more like hard coding, feels like there is some easier way of doing it